# openat() recognized /dev/stdout as a directory

Tags: c, linux-kernel, glibc

Let's have a look at this demonstration program

```c
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void) {

    int fd = openat(AT_FDCWD, "/dev/stdout", O_RDONLY|O_PATH|O_DIRECTORY);
    if (fd == -1) {
        perror("openat");
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I've done a `ltrace` of this program, and here is the important part:

When compiled using a `3.10.0-693` linux kernel the output is

```
__libc_start_main([ "./a.out" ] <unfinished ...>
openat(0xffffff9c, 0x400670, 0x210000, 0x4005e0)      = 3
+++ exited (status 0) +++
```

When compiled using a `4.14.15-1` linux kernel the output is

```
__libc_start_main(0x40059d, 1, 0x7ffcaccd9e98, 0x4005e0 <unfinished ...>
openat(0xffffff9c, 0x400670, 0x210000, 0x4005e0)      = -1
perror("openat"openat: Not a directory
)                                                     = <void>
+++ exited (status 1) +++
```

So it seems the `openat()` recognized `/dev/stdout` as a directory in `3.10.0-693` linux kernel. From a logical point of view this is quiet unexpected.

I could not find this documented anywhere and it feels a bit like an edge case. Can anyone explain what exactly is going on here?

---

**Edit:** `strace` the program on kernel `3.10.0-693` produces:

```
mprotect(0x7f568f480000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
munmap(0x7f568f473000, 47716)           = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/dev/stdout", O_RDONLY|O_PATH|O_DIRECTORY) = 3
exit_group(0)                           = ?
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

Comment: I don't think "when compiled" is correct. Try providing `ls -ld /dev/stdout` on the machine where it is working. It could be messed up.

Comment: @Joshua The output is `lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 15 Jan 31 18:55 /dev/stdout -> /proc/self/fd/1`

Comment: I've reached the conclusion you've found a bug in an old distro. Not too sure what to do from here.

Comment: You should check with `strace` as well: maybe the libc on the old system is the one that doesn't support `O_DIRECTORY` (and doesn't pass it to the kernel). What libc is on both systems?

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' The results of `strace` have been added. I don't think this has much to do with `glibc`, because I statically linked `glibc 2.17` and tested it under the different kernels above and it reproduced the issue, so I think it's more likely to be a syscall problem.

Comment: Then this does look like a kernel bug. The version number looks like RHEL, have you checked the patch notes for subsequent updates?

Comment: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v3.10.108/source/fs/namei.c#L1850 vs https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.14.304/source/fs/namei.c#L2174 . I'll guess this commit https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/97242f99a013950af63effa0732f8ef7db4e31ec . Do you want to test kernel v4.1 vs v.4.2?

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' The distro I use is `CentOS Linux release 7.4.1708 (Core)`. Let me go through it again.

Comment: @KamilCuk I don't have kernel v4.1 or v.4.2 environments on hand right now (: